# Generar un txt en php con cabecera y detalle

Tags: php, txt

quiero generar reportes en txt PHP.

Pero no obtengo el resultado deseado. Necesito que me muestre solo el encabezado una sola vez.
Y me lo repite.

Este es mi código:

```
 $sqlPol = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM polizasap_enc a
                            RIGHT join polizasap_det b
                            on a.id_Rec = b.id_Rec");
$file = 'datos.txt';
$jump = "\r\n";
$separator = "  ";

$fp = fopen($file , 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");;

foreach ($sqlPol as $key => $row) {

    $registroCab = $row['tipoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['claseDoc'] . $separator . $row['fechaDoc'] . $separator  . $row['fechaCont']. $separator  . $row['referencia']. $separator . $row['texto']. $jump;

    $registroDet = $row['tpoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['ctaContable'] . $separator . $row['importe'] . $separator  . $row['moneda']. $separator  . $row['posPre']. $separator . $row['txtPosicion']. $jump;

     fwrite($fp, $registroCab.$registroDet);
}
fclose($fp);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas agregar una variable para comparar con el último contenido mostrado en cada iteración, creas encabezados solo si es diferente del anterior:

```
$sqlPol = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM polizasap_enc a
                            RIGHT join polizasap_det b
                            on a.id_Rec = b.id_Rec");
$file = 'datos.txt';
$jump = "\r\n";
$separator = "  ";
// Variable para saber si se deben enviar encabezados
$registro = '';
// Variable para crear encabezados cada 2 registros
$cuenta = 0;
$fp = fopen($file , 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");;

foreach ($sqlPol as $key => $row) {
    // Inicializar encabezados
    $registroCab = '';
    // Si el texto es diferente de la última iteración
    if($registro != $row['texto'] || $cuenta == 2) {
        // Mostrar encabezados
        $registroCab = $row['tipoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['claseDoc'] . $separator . $row['fechaDoc'] . $separator  . $row['fechaCont']. $separator  . $row['referencia']. $separator . $row['texto']. $jump;
        $registro = $row['texto'];
        $cuenta = 0;
    }

    $registroDet = $row['tpoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['ctaContable'] . $separator . $row['importe'] . $separator  . $row['moneda']. $separator  . $row['posPre']. $separator . $row['txtPosicion']. $jump;

     fwrite($fp, $registroCab.$registroDet);
     $cuenta ++;
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Si te sirvió, por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Una duda, si el texto es el mismo pero cambia la fecha o cualquier texto de la cabecera como le podría hacer?

Comment: Una duda, si el texto es el mismo pero cambia la fecha o cualquier texto de la cabecera como le podría hacer?

Comment: Creas toda la cabecera y la comparas con la anterior, en lugar de comparar solo un dato.

Comment: Listo funciona muy bien. Ultimo detalle ya para finalizar, espero me puedas ayudar. Si la cabecera no cambia como le podría hacer? Forzosamente cada 2 registros hay que poner una cabecera.

Comment: Agrega un contador (ya está en la respuesta), cada vez que sume 2 se van a mostrar los encabezados y se inicializa para volver a contar.

Comment: Gracias. Solución completa. Te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: @PedroIslasReséndiz ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

Condicionalo para que se impruima una sola vez.

```
 $sqlPol = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM polizasap_enc a
                            RIGHT join polizasap_det b
                            on a.id_Rec = b.id_Rec");
$file = 'datos.txt';
$jump = "\r\n";
$separator = "  ";

$fp = fopen($file , 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");;
$cabecera= false;
foreach ($sqlPol as $key => $row) {
    if(!$cabecera){
     $cabecera = true;
        $registroCab = $row['tipoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['claseDoc'] . $separator . $row['fechaDoc'] . $separator  . $row['fechaCont']. $separator  . $row['referencia']. $separator . $row['texto']. $jump;
    }else{
        $registroCab="";
    }

    $registroDet = $row['tpoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['ctaContable'] . $separator . $row['importe'] . $separator  . $row['moneda']. $separator  . $row['posPre']. $separator . $row['txtPosicion']. $jump;

     fwrite($fp, $registroCab.$registroDet);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Gracias, por tu respuesta. Solo que la cabecera cambia cada dos registros y con el codigo que me compartes solo se queda una cabecera.